# Ingnore index if already exist and create/add new index in elasticsearch with nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and also for couchbase and I want to replicate documents from couchbase to elasticsearch using nodejs.

Below are the indexes we have in couchbase:

```
const destinationIndexes = {
indexName: 'idx_dest'
fields: ["id", "name"]
options: { ignoreIfExists: true }
}

const testIndexes = {
indexName: 'idx_test',
fields: ["testName", "test", "testId"]
options: { ignoreIfExists: true }
}

const statusIndexes = {
indexName: 'idx_status',
fields: ["statusSchema"]
options: { ignoreIfExists: true }
}
```

I tried to create a similar index in elasticsearch with below code

```
const createIndex = async function(indexName){
    return await client.indices.create({
       index: indexName
    });
}

indexes.forEach((item) =>{
    console.log('..........item'+item)
    const resp =  createIndex(item.indexName);
    console.log('...........resp..............'+JSON.stringify(resp))
})
```

I'm able to create index,but if I rerun the code, it shows error:
[resource_already_exists_exception] index [idx_dest/0iR-fZLdSty0oLVaQhNTXA] already exists, with { index_uuid="0iR-fZLdSty0oLVaQhNTXA" & index="idx_dest" }

I want it to ignore the existing index and add a new index if any.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 6):

You want to only create an index if it does not exist yet. Do so by
first checking for it's existence before creating it using `client.indices.exists()`.

So this could be modified `createIndex()`

```js
const createIndex = async function(indexName){
    if(await client.indices.exists({index: indexName})) {
        // returning false since no index was created.. 
        console.log('Index', indexName, 'does already exist')
        return false
    }
    return await client.indices.create({
       index: indexName
    });
}
```